# Web page loads slow from certain IP address

Tags: linux, apache-2.4, linux-networking, website, slow-connection

Good morning,

We're having a bizarre issue: from certain IP address (specifically our main IP address), our web pages load pretty slow. It's only one IP address which we're having this incident. If we try it with another address, for example:

If we try connecting to the web page www.example.com from 1.1.1.1 (using web browser), the site loads pretty slow, but from IP 1.1.1.2, 1.1.2.1, 1.2.1.1, 2.1.1.1, 192.168.1.4, 201.23.65.143, etc. it loads fine.

This has driven us crazy. The network with the ip 1.1.1.1 loads every page pretty well except those inside that server. Also, the load in the server and in the database it's pretty fine.

Do you know what can possibly be? what is causing this issue or something like that? It's pretty annoying. I'm thinking that it's something inside the server, because it's only the pages inside that server (Wordpress), but we don't really know what is it. If you need more details, I'll be at the lookout (can't give many information, but I'll try to do my best).

Thanks for your attention,

Regards,

Comment: Have you tried the ping from those ip? Are the response time similar and any packet drops?

Comment: Hi there, yeah, I've tried with ping and traceroute but everything seems fine. Also when doing ssh to the server, I hadn't note any slowness.

Comment: Are the statistics summary of curl command line similar?

Comment: Hi there, yes, curl seems to bring the webpage just fine.

Comment: When doing this: `curl -w '\nLookup time:\t%{time_namelookup}\nConnect time:\t%{time_connect}\nPreXfer time:\t%{time_pretransfer}\nStartXfer time:\t%{time_starttransfer}\n\nTotal time:\t%{time_total}\n' -o /dev/null -s http://www.example.com/` brings me this:

Lookup time: 0.002

Connect time: 0.080

PreXfer time: 0.080

StartXfer time: 1.706

Total time: 2.439

Comment: If the curl results look similar among those ip, the web browser in 1.1.1.1 may get an issue, not relate to your server or your web pages

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your replies. I got a report from a team member that is working from his house. He made the same command with another IP and another bandwidth (much lesser than ours) and got the following:
Lookup time: 0.001  -  Connect time: 0.069
PreXfer time: 0.069  -  StartXfer time: 0.125
--
Total time: 0.125

Comment: Another folk did the same and got: Lookup time: 0.002 -Connect time: 0.052 - PreXfer time: 0.052
StartXfer time: 0.105
--
Total time: 0.105

Comment: Are they all from 1.1.1.1? How about the other ip?

Comment: Hi there! Nop, this folks are working from their houses, their ip are different from ours inside the office. From here, the curl takes from 2.3 to 2.7 seconds and from there it takes from 0.102 to 0.125

Comment: I would also add %D (time to serve in microseconds) to your LogFormat to see how fast Apache is actually serving the data for the two IPs. If they are the same from Apache's point of view then it's likely you have a problem on the network somewhere. If it is very different you may want to use mod_dumpio to try to get an idea as to where the time is being taken up.